# Chart js with different width in x-axis

Tags: chart.js

Hi Can anyone tell me how to get two different ticks for x-axis with different widths in chart js ? I also need to thicken the y axis lines at 3,4,5,6 month's tick

I'm trying to implement WHO chart "Weight-for-age BOYS - Birth to 2 years (z-scores)" in my application.

[image]